# Pegar os elementos em volta de um selecionado na matriz

Tags: c#, .net, algoritmo, matriz

A ideia é criar uma matriz de inteiros com a quantidade de linhas e colunas definidas pelo usuário. Em seguida um valor existente na matriz deve ser informado e o programa deve retornar os valores imediatamente a esquerda, direita, acima e abaixo da matriz.

#### Exemplo

> ```
> Número de Linhas: 3
> Número de Colunas: 4
>
> 10 7 15 12
> 21 11 23 8
> 14 5 13 19 
>
> Número que deseja verificar: 11
>
> Esquerda: 21
> Direita: 23
> Acima: 7
> Abaixo: 5
> ```

O código que desenvolvi funciona perfeitamente quando inserido um valor da matriz que não esteja no 'canto'. Se eu informar um valor que esteja no 'canto' o programa lança a exceção `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` indicando que não há valores imediatamente acima/a esquerda/abaixo/ a direita do valor desejado.

Como eu poderia tratar esta exceção? Quaisquer dicas são bem vindas já que meu objetivo é aprender. Segue meu código para análise.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] Linha = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int[,] Numeros = new int[int.Parse(Linha[0]), int.Parse(Linha[1])];

            for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(Linha[0]); i++)
            {
                string[] vet = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                for (int j = 0; j < int.Parse(Linha[1]); j++)
                {
                    Numeros[i, j] = int.Parse(vet[j]);
                }
            }

            string[] Localizacao = new string[4];
            int Num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(Linha[0]); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < int.Parse(Linha[1]); j++)
                {
                    if (Numeros[i, j] == Num)
                    {
                        Localizacao[0] = Numeros[i, j - 1].ToString();
                        Localizacao[1] = Numeros[i, j + 1].ToString();
                        Localizacao[2] = Numeros[i - 1, j].ToString();
                        Localizacao[3] = Numeros[i + 1, j].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Esquerda: " + Localizacao[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("Direita: " + Localizacao[1]);
            Console.WriteLine("Acima: " + Localizacao[2]);
            Console.WriteLine("Abaixo: " + Localizacao[3]);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Essa exceção normalmente ocorre quando uma instrução tenta acessar um elemento em um índice maior que o índice máximo permitido.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O primeiro ponto é evitar entrar dados na forma atual. E testar os dados entrados porque pode digitar errado. Eu deixei esta forma pouco intuitiva, mas testei por erros de digitação.

O erro mesmo é que se o dado a ser procurado for na linha ou coluna 0 ou for na linha ou coluna final no momento que ele pega -1 o índice será -1 e quando pega +1 pega um valor acima do que existe, e dá erro. Então o que eu fiz é que mostrar só os lados existentes e deixei em branco o que não existe.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        string[] linha = ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int linhas;
        if (!int.TryParse(linha[0], out linhas)) return;
        int colunas;
        if (!int.TryParse(linha[1], out colunas)) return;
        int[,] numeros = new int[linhas, colunas];
        for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
            string[] vet = ReadLine().Split(' ');
            for (int j = 0; j < colunas; j++) {
                int valor;
                if (!int.TryParse(vet[j], out valor)) return;
                numeros[i, j] = valor;
            }
        }
        string[] localizacao = new string[4];
        int num;
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out num)) return;
        for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colunas; j++) {
                if (numeros[i, j] == num) {
                    localizacao[0] = j == 0 ? "" : numeros[i, j - 1].ToString();
                    localizacao[1] = j == numeros.GetUpperBound(1) ? "" : numeros[i, j + 1].ToString();
                    localizacao[2] = i == 0 ? "" : numeros[i - 1, j].ToString();
                    localizacao[3] = i == numeros.GetUpperBound(0) ? "" : numeros[i + 1, j].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        WriteLine("Esquerda: " + localizacao[0]);
        WriteLine("Direita: " + localizacao[1]);
        WriteLine("Acima: " + localizacao[2]);
        WriteLine("Abaixo: " + localizacao[3]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TL9mZX). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tjsNGU). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/GetLateral.cs).

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda.
Tem bastante métodos e classes no seu código que eu tenho que dar uma estudada para entender completamente.

Comment: Sim, e se não fizer isto o código se comportará errado. Na verdade acho que só 2 métodos e provavelmente 1 operador. Um deles pode deixar de usar porque já tem a informação, mas achei interessante conhecer.

Answer (score 6):

O problema está no facto de alguns índices estarem a ultrapassar os limites do `Array`, seja para mais (mais do o índice máximo) ou para menos (-1).

A solução será validar tudo antes de atribuir o valor à `Localizacao`:

```
if (Numeros[i, j] == Num)
{
    if(j - 1 >= 0)
        Localizacao[0] = Numeros[i, j - 1].ToString();
    else
    {
        // código de controlo
    }

    if(j + 1 < Linha[1])
        Localizacao[1] = Numeros[i, j + 1].ToString();
    else
    {
        // código de controlo
    }

    if(i - 1 >= 0)
        Localizacao[2] = Numeros[i - 1, j].ToString();
    else
    {
        // código de controlo
    }

    if(i + 1 < Linha[0])
        Localizacao[3] = Numeros[i + 1, j].ToString();
    else 
    {
        // código de controlo
    }
}
```

O `código de controlo` é onde deverá colocar a instrução a usar quando o limite, máximo ou mínimo, é atingido.

Se o objetivo é mostrar uma mensagem caso os índices sejam excedidos, pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
if (Numeros[i, j] == Num)
{
    if(j - 1 >= 0 || j + 1 < Linha[1] || i - 1 >= 0 || i + 1 < Linha[0])
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Os índices da matriz foram excedidos.");
    }
    else
    {
        Localizacao[0] = Numeros[i, j - 1].ToString();
        Localizacao[1] = Numeros[i, j + 1].ToString();
        Localizacao[2] = Numeros[i - 1, j].ToString();
        Localizacao[3] = Numeros[i + 1, j].ToString();
    }
}
```

Existe também dois métodos interessantes para validar os limites de uma matriz: `GetLength`:

```
int[,] Numeros = new int[2, 3];

int x = Numeros.GetLength(0);   // devolve 2
int y = Numeros.GetLength(1);   // devolve 3
```

Answer (score -2):

Para que o programa respeite o exemplo mostrado, além de fazer a sanitização das entradas do usuário, pode-se fazer o programa da seguinte forma:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static class Vector
        {
            public static bool TryParse(string input, int columns, out IEnumerable<int> decodedValues)
            {
                var list = new List<int>();
                bool result = false;

                string[] sanity = input.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                if (sanity.Length != columns)
                {
                    result = false;
                }
                else if (sanity.All(entry => int.TryParse(entry, out int dummy)))
                {
                    result = true;
                    list.AddRange(sanity.Select(entry => int.Parse(entry)));
                }

                decodedValues = list;
                return result;
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var (lines, columns) = GetLinesAndColumns();
            var matrix = GetMatrix(lines, columns).ToArray();
            var selectedValue = GetSelectedValue();

            DisplayNorthSouthEastWest(selectedValue, matrix, lines, columns);
        }

        public static (int, int) GetLinesAndColumns()
        {
            string input = null;
            int lines;
            int columns;

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Número de linhas: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (!int.TryParse(input, out lines));

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Número de colunas: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (!int.TryParse(input, out columns));

            Console.WriteLine();

            return (lines, columns);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<int> GetMatrix(int lines, int columns)
        {
            string input = null;
            IEnumerable<int> result = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < lines; ++i)
            { 
                do
                {
                    Console.Write($"    {i+1}: ");
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                } while (!Vector.TryParse(input, columns, out result));

                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public static int GetSelectedValue()
        {
            string input = null;
            int selectedValue;
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Número que deseja verificar: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (!int.TryParse(input, out selectedValue));

            Console.WriteLine();

            return selectedValue;
        }

        public static void DisplayNorthSouthEastWest(int selectedValue, int[] matrix, int lines, int columns)
        {
            var vector = matrix.ToArray();

            int selectedIndex = Array.FindIndex(vector, item => item == selectedValue);

            if (selectedIndex < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Número que deseja verificar, {selectedValue}, não está na matriz.");
            }
            else
            { 
                int temp;
                int north = selectedIndex - columns;
                int south = selectedIndex + columns;
                int west  = (temp = selectedIndex) % columns == 0       ? -1 : temp - 1;
                int east  = (temp = (selectedIndex + 1)) % columns == 0 ? -1 : temp;

                string northString = north < 0 ?              "Não há" : vector[north].ToString();
                string southString = south >= vector.Length ? "Não há" : vector[south].ToString();
                string westString  = west < 0 ?               "Não há" : vector[west].ToString();
                string eastString  = east < 0 ?               "Não há" : vector[east].ToString();

                Console.WriteLine($"Esquerda : {westString}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Direita  : {eastString}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Acima    : {northString}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Abaixo   : {southString}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Poderia editar a resposta e inserir uma descrição a respeito da sua resposta?